# Fechar botão ok no popup com Selenium Driver

Tags: javafx, selenium-webdriver

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta de testes usando selenium driver em java.

O portal que estou testando apresenta um pop-up ou uma caixa de dialogo, onde possui um botão de OK.
Minha ferramenta precisa pressionar .clik() neste botão,não consigo selecionar o id do botão, pois não consigo utilizar o F12 nem o xpath, para identificar o html do pop-up.

Encontrei este código, porém sem identificar o id do botão a ação dele não é exercida.

```
driver.switchTo().window("[handle da sua janela]");
driver.close();
```

`insira o código aqui`// Ou um click no caminho do botão ok

O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

considerando que ele seja apenas um alerta você pode simplesmente fazer o seguinte:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

dá pra chamar o método dismiss() também, se por exemplo ele for uma daquelas opções com OK/Cancel, ai o accept() nesse caso clicaria no ok e o dismiss() no cancel.

Comment: Obrigada, @Lucas, eu já tinha conseguido revolver, mas não conhecia o dismiss(), agora já aprendi mais um comando.